# DNS lookup intermidetly fails after previously working

Tags: web, dns

This morning I tried to visit a website I run, only to see that the dns lookup failed, this problem is visible on multiple devices and broswers.  This was surprising to me - things were running fine yesterday.  What are some possible causes for why a websites dns can just stop resolving?

The specific domain I'm working with is [candocomputing.com](http://candocomputing.com).  [Warning: commercial link]

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?

Comment: Sure thing, just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from 192.5.6.30 (a.gtld-servers.net):

```
;; QUESTION SECTION (1  record)
;; candocomputing.com.  IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION (2  records)
candocomputing.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns2.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com.
candocomputing.com. 172800  IN  NS  ns1.verification-hold.suspended-domain.com.
```

According to [this](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/domain-order-validation), looks like you did not respond to verification email within 15 days after registration and now your domain is suspended.